# Write $h \in V^*$, defined by $h(p(x)) = p'(x)$ as a linear combination of the functionals in $\beta^*$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Let $\beta^*$={f1, f2} be a basis of $V^*$, where $V= P_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_1(p(x))=p(1)$ and $f_2(p(x))=p(2)$.
Write $h \in V^*$, defined by $h(p(x)) = p'(x)$ as a linear combination of the functionals in
$\beta^*$.

I've been stuck on this homework problem for a while no and am just stumped on what to do, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $p(x)=ax+b$ then $p'(x)=a=(2a+b)-(a+b) =p(2)-p(1)$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. How would I write this as a linear combination? WOuld I be able to say that $p'(x)=p(2)-p(1)$ is the linear combination since $\beta^*={f_1,f_2}$?

Comment: What is "the name" of $p(1)$ or $p(2)$ in $\beta^*$?

Comment: $f_1(p(x))$ and $f_2(p(x))$, right?

Comment: I think you can finish by your own